# Prevent WKWebView to handle media keys events

Tags: swift, macos, media-player

I'm working on native media player for macOS. It should be a simple music streaming website wrapper with global support of media-keys.

Interface of the App it's just full sized WKWebView. Everything works fine with `MPRemoteCommandCenter` to handle media keys events like play/pause until browser starts playing audio. It's looks like browser is overriding method `addTarget(Any, action: Selector)` for instance of class `MPRemoteCommand` and my custom handlers haven't called anymore.

Is there a way for `WKWebView` instance to prevent interception access to `MPRemoteCommandCenter` and/or `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter`?